# How to use current subdomain in url helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, devise

I have a url helper from Devise as follows:

```
account_confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token)
```

How do I make it create the url with the current subdomain instead of just the main subdomain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try passing it :host => 'yoursub.domain.com'

Comment: I think he wants it to happen automatically.

Answer (score 14):

The main solution described in the Devise wiki doesn’t work for setting arbitrary subdomains and is a problem if you’re triggering generation of email during a request in one subdomain (or the root domain of your application) and want the links in the email to reference a different subdomain.

The generally accepted way to make it work is to give the `url_for` helper a `:subdomain` option.

```
# app/helpers/subdomain_helper.rb

module SubdomainHelper
  def with_subdomain(subdomain)
    subdomain = (subdomain || "")
    subdomain += "." unless subdomain.empty?
    host = Rails.application.config.action_mailer.default_url_options[:host]
    [subdomain, host].join
  end

  def url_for(options = nil)
    if options.kind_of?(Hash) && options.has_key?(:subdomain)
      options[:host] = with_subdomain(options.delete(:subdomain))
    end
    super
  end
end
```

The next step is crucial and I suspect it is where a lot of people get tripped up (I know I did). Make sure that Devise mixes your new subdomain helper into its mailer objects by adding the following code to `config/application.rb`

```
  config.to_prepare do
    Devise::Mailer.class_eval do 
      helper :subdomain 
    end
  end
```

Now when you do a `link_to` in your Devise mailer template, you can easily specify a `:subdomain` option.

```
link_to 'Click here to finish setting up your account on RightBonus',
  confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @resource.confirmation_token, :subdomain => @resource.subdomain)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can look at Devise wiki:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Send-emails-from-subdomains